# CSS overflow issue with nested divs

Tags: css, html, overflow

I am creating a music website for a client, and trying to use a single page layout so the music player will not be interrupted during navigation. I have used the css attribute overflow:hidden on the divs for each section, but for some reason it will not recognize when I nest another div inside with the overflow:auto element. This is problematic because there is planned content that is not going to fit within a single page, such as comments, posts, and image thumbnails.

The page is live here: 
http://www.dennispiano.com

and my test server (with some undeployed content) here: `http://205.209.87.168/DennisMusic/index.php`

An example of what I am talking about is the images section (on the test server link, not yet deployed to live site)

Relevant HTML

```
<div class="contentbody">

<div id="images" class="pageSection">
     <h1 style="padding:0 0 0 10px; background-color:#00c7c0;">
     <img src="images/pageAssets/images.png" alt="Home" height="25" width="83" /></h1>
     <?php include('lib/php/thumbnails.php'); ?>
</div>

<!-- end .contentBody --></div>
```

Relevant PHP

```
//Variable Declaration (remove after xml structure creation)
$images=80;
$thumblimit=5;
$imagelines=($images/$thumblimit);

//

echo '<div class="sectionContent">'; //<-- busted content scrolling div
//Display Thumbnail tiles
for($i=0;$i<$imagelines;$i++) {

     echo '<div>';
     for($ii=0;$ii<$thumblimit;$ii++) {
          echo '<div style="display:block; margin:0 10px 0 10px; border:1px solid #fff;     background-color:#c90; width:50px; height:50px; float:left;"></div>';
     }
     echo '</div><br /><br /><br /><br />';

}

echo '</div>';

?>
```

Relevant CSS

```
.contentBody {
    overflow:hidden;
}

.pageSection {
        width:100%;
        min-height: 700px;
        display:block;
}

.sectionContent {
        overflow:auto;
        display:block;
        width:100%;
}
```

Comment: I've also tried using overflow:scroll, which displayed the scrollbar correctly, but still would not let the content scroll.

Comment: Please post relevant code about the issue, or a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: It would render correctly here, just read the help on code coloring.